# How to set a field validity based in API response

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have an Angular 4 app with a registration form. On submission I get from the API the info where is set if the username or email is taken (server validation rules). I'm trying to find a way similar to the **NgModelController** in AngularJS `$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid)` to set the field validity for reactive forms but I can't. I just want to set the validation after API response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing reactive form's input element's validation status manually(with custom error),

you can use `setError()` to change status to `error`:

```
this.form.controls.name.setErrors({'testError': true});
```

and clear errors by

```
this.form.controls.name.setErrors(null);
```

refer **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iH2OJZ3lhsIl0SilA65a?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works. Let me make you another question, with this approach I can control manually the field validation but when I have a series of validations I want to show an specific message for this case. How can I archive it?

Comment: @aUXcoder in the example at my answer, I have add a custom message based on specific validate error, you can show the message by `form.controls.name.hasError('customError')`. Let me know if you have further problem. :-)